# TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/MyProject

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

**I'm trying to connect my project to Azure DevOps with VS 2017.**
Reason: Migration from DevOps On-Premises to Azure-DevOps.
Error: TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/MyProject
Login: two factor authentication.
**How can I create a test plan on my project in Azure DevOps with VS 2017?**

I'm already connected with Azure-DevOps in VS 2017 and I can see my Project with Browser (**Visual Studio, View->Other Windows->Web Browser**). But with Code I can't get access

```
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("username@mail.com", "password");
BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(netCred);
TfsClientCredentials tfsCred = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);
tfsCred.AllowInteractive = false;

TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(_newServer), tfsCred);

 tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
 tpc.Authenticate();

Log in with two factor authentication
```

Comment: I did clean cache TFS folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use mail account directly, use Alternate Credentials (`https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_usersSettings/altcreds`) instead.

Or you can use personal access token

```
VssCredentials Credentials = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "your personal acccess token"));
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/{org{"), Credentials);
```

You also could specify the email account during runtime:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://{org}.visualstudio.com"), new VssClientCredentials());
```

NuGet package: [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient)

Comment: It only worked with "Alternate Credentials". Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Consider to use [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/) nuget package. try the followin steps:

- Create PAT: [Authenticate access with personal access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops)
- Use this sample code to authenticate:

```
string PAT = "<your_pat>";
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("<your_url>"), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, PAT));
TestPlanClient = Connection.GetClient<TestPlanHttpClient>();
```

- Then you can create a test plan

```
TestPlanCreateParams newPlanDef = new TestPlanCreateParams()
{
    Name = TestPlanName,
    StartDate = StartDate,
    EndDate = FinishDate,
    AreaPath = AreaPath,
    Iteration = IterationPath
};

var test_plan =  TestPlanClient.CreateTestPlanAsync(newPlanDef, TeamProjectName).Wait();
```

Comment: I trid with VssConnection, unfortunately it did not work

Comment: @MajdiBarrat There is a sample project, you can try it here: [Create a test plan and test suite](https://github.com/ashamrai/TFRestApi/tree/master/13.TFRestApiAppCreateTestPlanAndSuites)